# Python, Pandas: to filter and drop variables less than 5

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

Columns with list of the manager's phone numbers:

datetime    |client |manager
xx          |xx      |+44....
The task is to calculate how many calls from each number made...
df['mmanager'].value_counts()

and after - to filter phone numbers in the list: to drop rows with numbers less than 5 calls.

## Example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import product, chain

managers = [f"{manager}_{i}" for i, manager in product(range(3),("Bob", "Silvie", "Steve"))]
clients = [f"{client}_{i}" for i, client in product(range(20),("Lukas", "Max", "Julia"))]

weights = np.array([100.0]*len(managers))
weights[:5] = 1
weights *= 1/sum(weights)

np.random.seed(0)
size = 10**3
df = pd.DataFrame({"manager": np.random.choice(managers,size=size, p=weights),"clients": np.random.choice(clients,size=size)})
df.value_counts("manager").sort_values().head(10)
```

gives

```
manager
Steve_0       1
Bob_1         1
Bob_0         2
Silvie_0      3
Silvie_1      4
Steve_2     238
Silvie_2    240
Steve_1     252
Bob_2       259
dtype: int64
```

So I want `Steve_0, Bob_1, Bob_0, Silvie_0 and Silvie_1` removed from the list.

Comment: show a sample of data

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for new column or `Series`, last compare by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) for greater like `5` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['count'] = df['mmanager'].map(df['mmanager'].value_counts())

df = df[df['count'].gt(5)]
```

If need solution without helper column:

```
df = df[df['mmanager'].map(df['mmanager'].value_counts()).gt(5)]
```